# how to filter nested json data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a json data like this:

```
{
"body":"message1",
"date":"2015-..",
"folder":{
  "itemId":"3",
  "name":"type1"
},
"subject":"subject"
}
```

I am trying to filter based on folder.name. this is my  html code.

```
<div ng-repeat="msg in messages |filter:{folder.name:'type1'}">
```

but I am getting syntax error. how to filter nested json data in html view.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div ng-repeat="msg in messages |filter:{folder: {name:'type1'}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things.  Ng-Repeat is expecting a collection(array) not an object, like this:

```
[{
   body: "message1",
   date: "2015-..",
   folder: {
        itemId: "3",
        name: "type1"
   },
   subject: "subject"
 }]
```

Then your html should look like this:

```
  <div ng-repeat="msg in messages | filter: {folder:{name:'type1'}}">
```